# How to use different labels for a button in Angular library for different application?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a library named as *lib-survey* which uses Angular Formly and has a button that review the survey.

```
 <div class="row-xs-12">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <formly-form
         #formly
         [options]="options"
         [model]="surveyModel"
         [fields]="currentFormlyFields"
         (modelChange)="modelChange($event)"
         [form]="form.form">
      </formly-form>
      <button
         class="btn btn-primary"
         type="submit"
         (click)="openReview()"> Review </button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This library is used in multiple applications just like this.

```
<lib-survey
   [appType]="app1"
   [appId]="1"
</lib-survey>
```

How can I change the label for the button for different applications?

For example, when used in App1, button label should be "*Review Answer*", but for App2, button label should be "*Review Survey*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical use-case of parent-to-child communication in Angular. So you can use the `@Input` decorator in this scenario.

In the `component.ts` of the **button** declare a variable,

```
@Input buttonLabel: string;
```

In the HTML just use the same same label for interpolating button name,

```
 <div class="row-xs-12">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <formly-form
         #formly
         [options]="options"
         [model]="surveyModel"
         [fields]="currentFormlyFields"
         (modelChange)="modelChange($event)"
         [form]="form.form">
      </formly-form>
      <button
         class="btn btn-primary"
         type="submit"
         (click)="openReview()">{{ buttonLabel }} </button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now whenever you are using the button component just pass the name of the buttonLabel as well,

```
<lib-survey
   [appType]="app1"
   [appId]="1"
   [buttonLabel]="Something"
</lib-survey>
```